# Azure.RequestFailedException: The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob. in azure function?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-cosmosdb, azure-webjobs, timer-trigger

Good Day,

I am working with azure function(v4) and I am receiving an error in my Splunk with the status saying "Status: 409 (The lease ID specified did not match the lease ID for the blob.)"
with stack trace as below.

```
 at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.RenewLeaseAsync(String leaseId, Nullable`1 
 timeout, Nullable`1 ifModifiedSince, Nullable`1 ifUnmodifiedSince, String ifMatch, 
 String 
 ifNoneMatch, String ifTags, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobLeaseClient.RenewInternal(RequestConditions 
 conditions, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
 at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobLeaseClient.RenewAsync(RequestConditions 
 conditions, CancellationToken cancellationToken) 
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.SingletonLockHandle.
 RenewAsync( 
 ILogger logger, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
 C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk- 
 rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Storage\
 Singleton\BlobLeaseDistributedLockManager.cs:line 394
 at 
 Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.SingletonManager.RenewLeaseCommand.
 ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk- 
 rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\
 SingletonManager.cs:line 347
 at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.
 RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
 C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk- 
 rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs:line 147
```

Currently, we are working with cosmos DB and Azure functions. I have added a few loggers in my code and I am still struggling to find out why it is coming. Could someone please help me with this?

And my host.json as below

```
 {
   "version": "2.0",
   "extensions": {
   "http": {
  "routePrefix": "ServiceSubscriber"
          }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you get this when the host starts? Check out the following comment about 429s and lease: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2318#issuecomment-525738921

Comment: HI @MikeUrnunMSFT, My apologies for the delay in reply. My code has a lot of timer triggers, and the issue coming intermittently. But not sure what could be the reason. I have done some R&D, but couldn't find any solution.